# QT HTTP Get Request SSL Error

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

I am simply trying to send a GET Request using HTTP URL and I am getting these two SSL Errors:

```
>     qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function d2i_DHparams
>     qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function DH_free
```

I am using Windows 10 with QTCreator (QT v5.8), and I am aware that the SSL Libraries are not imported by QT by default. However, I am sending an HTTP Request and not HTTPS, so why would I be getting SSL Errors?

Here is the code snippet producing the error:

```
void MainWindow::sendGetRequest(QString& url)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;
    QNetworkRequest request;

    QUrl httpRequest(url);

    request.setUrl(httpRequest);
    currentReply = networkManager.get(request);
    ui->label_2->setText("Request Sent...");

    connect(&networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onGetRequestResult(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void MainWindow::onGetRequestResult(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        ui->label_2->setText("Get Request Error!");
        return;
    }

    QString data = (QString) reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << data;

}
```

Right after the label changes to `Request Sent...` the errors are thrown and  the slot `onGetRequestResult()` is never called.

Also, I have downloaded the two SSL Binaries but that doesn't change anything and is there a way to disable SSL for GET Request since I don't need to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question by adding your previous comment.

Comment: There is probably a redirect to https in the response of the HTTP request and the HTTP stack from Qt is following it and trying to reach the site by https as ordered by the server.

Comment: Let's assume the response is going through an SSL, but still how do I fix those errors? If I use `curl -X Get "url"` it works just fine. However, I don't have the privilege of using `curl` on Windows 10.

Comment: Get the OpenSSL DLLs and put them in PATH / next to your app's .exe / etc?

Comment: @PrateekKhatri, listen to what jorp is saying.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Here's the solution that worked for me.

1. Download the installation package from this site
   http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. Install it to any location.
3. Copy the OpenSSL DLLs to the OpenSSL binaries (\bin) directory.
4. Copy libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll and ssleay32.dll from the \bin folder to the same place where your QtNetwork4.dll or QtNetworkd4.dll is located.

I hope this helps! : )

Answer (score 0):

Is some QT windows bug, if you use qt mingw gcc 32bit, copy to your windows application executable location ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll. In my case is:
  Qt\Qt5.8.0\Tools\mingw530_32\opt\bin\ssleay32.dll
  Qt\Qt5.8.0\Tools\mingw530_32\opt\bin\libeay32.dll

Answer (score -1):

`networkManager` is declared in

```
 `MainWindow::sendGetRequest()`,
```

after execution of

```
 `sendGetRequest()`,
```

`networkManager` is destroyed, then it's

`finished(QNetworkReply*)`

signal wouldn't be emitted.

you should declare `networkManager` as a member of `MainWindow`.
Or consider store it in heap

(`auto networkManger = new NetworkManager(this)`),

if it is only created once.